# Get linux 'screen' to recognize xterm mouse-click cols > 95

Tags: xterm, javascript, gnu-screen

I have a Web-based terminal using xterm.js and ssh2 from node.js.  When I click, xterm.js sends mouse-click coords via xterm escape sequences.  This works fine.  When using the 'screen' cli utility, anything greater than 95 columns is registered as 95 columns.  An example is, when using Midnight Commander over 'screen',  it only registers clicks past 95 cols at the 95th column.  Without 'screen', it works normally.  Is there an easy fix?

I'm using Ubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legacy mouse protocol uses raw bytes for each coordinate (the coordinate plus 32). As such, it only supports coordinates up to 223 (223 + 32 = 255, the biggest value a byte can hold).

In certain situations, e.g. when a character set conversion happens, or when some component requires that the data passing through is valid UTF-8, bytes in the 128-255 range also become problematic. As such, clicks only work reliably up to column and row 95.

I'm not familiar with xterm.js and your whole environment to tell whether you can tweak it to support coordinates up to 223 (e.g. by changing character encoding, although switching away from UTF-8 would also be a stupid move).

The proper solution would be to add support of the SGR 1006 mouse mode extension to `screen`, see https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?37206. This new protocol encodes the coordinates using ASCII digits, therefore removes the upper limit and gets rid of character encoding issues as well.

Until they address this, you might consider trying `tmux`. It's a more modern, more actively maintained alternative to `screen` and supports the said extension.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @egmont!  Yeah, it's a little tricky, my setup.  I wrote it myself with a couple libraries, so sometimes I have to debug whether a problem is in my own code or somebody elses.  Yes, the SGR plaintext encoded positions are the one's I'm using.  So it does appear 'screen' is the cause of my problem.  Is there a Debian/Ubuntu repo for the updated version?  I wonder why the update isn't compiled in by default.  I can work around it, but it'll be a problem for my users.  If switch to Tmux, how do I enable it to pass mouse escapes?  Can you tell it to identify as an 'xterm'?

Comment: @jdmayfield No clue why `screen` hasn't added this feature yet, probably they're short on developer resources. In `tmux` clicks beyond 223 work out of the box for me (assuming, of course, that both neighbors of tmux, that is, both the host terminal emulator and the app you're running supports it too). Not sure what you mean by the word "identify", tmux's emulation is similar to screen's and accordingly inside tmux you should have TERM=screen or something related, but tmux sets it up automatically for you.

Comment: Hey, @egmont!  Probably I will try tmux again.  The 'identify thing.. What I mean is 'screen' sets a custom 'TERM' type to 'screen', as opposed to whatever your actual terminal app or console is, i.e. on xterm usually TERM is set to 'xterm-color' or something like that, linux console usually TERM is 'linux'.  If your connected via putty it might be 'vt100' by default (don't remember off the top of my head).  'screen' has an option to change the terminal type when started via a command line option, and I think also the config file(s).  If not set explicitly it is TERM=screen, and I think tmux..

Comment: ..and i think tmux is TERM=tmux by default.  Anyway, I need it to start as TERM=xterm-color or xterm-color16.  Also, the cli options for screen let me auto-connect to the last session, or start new one automatically.  My system runs a series of commands remotely ending in the 'screen' command to set up some local options requiring data loaded from the server and leaving the user exactly where they left off without them having to do or know anything about 'screen' (or tmux if I go that route).  Anyway, thats the idea.  Basically mimics an xterm as far as the server is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @egmont.  I did end up switching to tmux.  To get everything to work, I had to change the TERM type from 'screen' to 'xterm-color'.  It's not recommended from what I read in the docs, but it works great.  Way less buggy than screen.  Only thing I really don't like is screen had explicit command-line options for identifying itself as a terminal of your choice.  None of the officially supported approaches worked universally.  Maybe I'm missing some feature(s) of tmux I don't use.  But everything seems to work.  Just like plain shell, but persistent sessions!  Love it.