# Screen command cuts off mouse at 95 columns

Tags: xterm, gnu-screen

I'm using the 'screen' command for a persistent shell session.  It seems to work pretty good, with a couple of caveats.

1. Mouse clicks only register as 95 columns or less.
2. The bottom line sometimes gets scrambled, disappears, or shows output from a different line.

Any suggestions how to fix this?  It's particjlarly noticable (and annoying) when using Midnight Commander.  Reconnecting temporarily alleves the line issue, but anytime I use a bigger window with more columns, and use 'screen', mouse-clicks only register at column 95 if the click is farther to the rignt than that.  I'm using Ubuntu LTS 16.0.4.3

Comment: As for the mouse click, see the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/972499/get-linux-screen-to-recognize-xterm-mouse-click-cols-95/980281. (I know it was you asking that question too. I'm posting the link here for anyone who comes across this question here.)

Comment: Thank you, @egmont.  I hit Ask Ubuntu as well as Super User because I hadn't recieved any responses-- that is, until you posted.  As important as terminals are, it seems there aren't many who know the in's and out's of escape sequences, or at least they aren't sharing!  Thank you, one again.